# Object [object Object] has no method 'nestedFields' - awesome_nested_fields gem - Rails 3.2 jquery-ui-1.9.2

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have installed this [pretty looking gem](https://github.com/lailsonbm/awesome_nested_fields) and have spent the last 2 hours trying to make it work.

I manage to display nested fields within the parent form and create/update records.

However, the add/remove JS links do not work. And this is because in the console is giving me this error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nestedFields' neste_attributes_forms.js:2
(anonymous function) neste_attributes_forms.    js:2
fire                                            jquery.js:1018
self.fireWith                                   jquery.js:1128
jQuery.extend.ready                             jquery.js:417
DOMContentLoaded
```

I am pretty new in JS. So, I am not sure what the problem is.

I have tried the same code it says on the gem page:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('FORM').nestedFields();
});
```

I have also tried calling by the id of the div. But, to not avail.
I have check the page source and it loads this piece of code.

Do you have any idea what I am missing? any help much appreciated!!!

The piece of the form: haml

```
= form_for(@event) do |f|
  ....somefields....

  #nested_layers   
    .items
      = f.nested_fields_for :details do |f|
        %fieldset.item
          = f.label :town
          = f.text_field :town
          %a.remove{:href => "#"} remove
          = f.hidden_field :id
          = f.hidden_field :_destroy
    %a.add{:href => "#"} add phone
  ..someOtherFields....
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min
//= require jquery.nested-fields
....
```

FIXED:
Application.js contains a really clever sentence that one should not delete:
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
So just make sure every //= require... is right below another. Otherwise you will miss methods!!

Comment: you have to add `//= require jquery.nested-fields` to `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`

Comment: I'd swear it is added. I can see it when inspecting the source.

Comment: is that line the last that is included? You should the lib being included in <head> when you open a page in browser

Comment: Not sure what you mean. But that line is not the last. Those are the first of the file. After that there is more, the that calls .nestedFields() aswell. Having a look at the source, it all loads inside the <head> tag.

Comment: Well... I am about to commit suicide!!! I just read // WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.  My visual organization made it not to work!

Comment: it does. The .js files the app was reading where from the cache. I just needed to delete them and fix my application.js. Thaaaaaanks for make me think!

Comment: I can post it as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the needed javascript lib is not loaded so make sure that:

```
//= require jquery.nested-fields
```

is properly included in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js`